# $X_n\rightarrow_{a.s.}Y $ implies $\frac{Z}{X_n}\rightarrow_{a.s.}\frac{Z}{Y} $

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Consider a sequence of real-valued random variables
$\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. Consider two other real-valued random variables $Y,Z$.

Suppose that
$$
X_n\rightarrow_{a.s.}Y \text{ }\text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$

---

Is it true that 
$$
\frac{Z}{X_n}\rightarrow_{a.s.}\frac{Z}{Y} \text{ }\text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$

Could you help me to prove it? Is this an application of continuous mapping theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a set $A$ with $P(A)=1$ such that all $X_n$ and $Y$ are $\neq 0$ on $A$, then it is true and can be proved directly. Otherwise it cannot be true because the fractions would not be even defined a.s.

Comment: Thank you. The proof is not related to continuous mapping theorem?

Comment: I see no connection. We have even other type of convergence here. Or do You know continuous mapping theorem for a.s. convergence?

Comment: Yes, See Van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics" Theorem 2.3 (iii): if $X_n\rightarrow_{a.s.}X$ then $g(X_n)\rightarrow_{a.s.}g(X)$

Comment: It's fine but we have not just $g(X_n)$ or $g(X)$. Moreover, the problem with zeros in the denominator remains. So I don't see what we win by trying to use the theorem. But it is related, somehow.

Comment: Could you help me with my other question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754594/pointwise-convergence-in-limit-of-conditional-probabilities-implies-almost-sure

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega \in \{ \lim X_n(\omega) = Y(\omega)\}$. Then

$$\lim_n \frac{Z(\omega)}{X_n(\omega)}= \frac{\lim_n Z(\omega)}{\lim_n X_n(\omega)}=\frac{Z(\omega)}{Y(\omega)} $$

Thus, $$\{ \lim X_n(\omega) = Y(\omega)\} \subseteq \{ \lim_n \frac{Z(\omega)}{X_n(\omega)}= \frac{\lim_n Z(\omega)}{\lim_n X_n(\omega)}=\frac{Z(\omega)}{Y(\omega)} \}$$

$$\to 1 = P(\{ \lim X_n(\omega) = Y(\omega)\}) \le P(\{ \lim_n \frac{Z(\omega)}{X_n(\omega)}= \frac{\lim_n Z(\omega)}{\lim_n X_n(\omega)}=\frac{Z(\omega)}{Y(\omega)} \})$$

QED